# Azure App service high memory usage. What to do post crash?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

we have observed a very high amount of memory usage previous night, So when we started troubleshooting in "Diagnose section" we observed the IIS process was consuming high memory followed by high CPU consumption which resulted in application crash. And the application automatically recovered. Is it possible to know which objects were consuming highest memory prior to crash and threads involved?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okYki.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQuho.png)